# How to improve SQL performance for search of top level domains

Tags: sql-server, optimization, dns

Trying to find a decent .com domain name so I downloaded complete list of .com domains from Verisign with the aim of running some SQL queries against it. One key goal is to run a query that checks dictionary sized list of English words to see if any don't have a.com domain. I don't use online service in part because I haven't found a service that gives me this sort of fine tune query control but it's also because I'm curious how to do this.

My first step was to import Verisign's com.zone file (a text file) into local developer version of SQL Server using built-in import flat file wizard. It created a column I named `RawData` (datatype `nvarchar(450)`, no nulls) in a table I named `Com`. It has ~352 million records. The records need some cleanup (e.g. don't need nameserver details, and some records don't seem parsed the same as others) but the domain names themselves seem to have been imported successfully.

I also created another table (~372K records, `nvarchar(450)`, no nulls) named `Words` which a column named `Word` that's a listing of most English words (e.g. the, internet, was, made, for, cat, videos, etc.. no definitions, just one word per record).

An immediate hurdle I've run into though is performance. Even a basic query to check availability of a single domain name is slow. When I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM Com 
WHERE RawData = '%insert-some-domain-name-here%'
```

the execution time is approximately 4 minutes (using laptop with i9-9880h, 32GB RAM, 2TB NVMe SSD).

Seeing as I'd prefer not to die of old age before any theoretical dictionary sized query ended, any suggestions on how to write the query and/or database alterations to get me to the end goal of reasonably fast search that generates a list of English words that don't have domain names.

Comment: Is there a non-clustered index on `RawData` ??

Comment: I would expect a singleton lookup to take microseconds if you have a unique index on `RawData`. The timings suggest you don't have such an index so all 352M rows must be scanned.

Comment: @marc_s No. I don't have an index. Should I use a clustered or non-clustered one? And what's the difference? (I'm a newb at SQL)

Comment: A clustered index should be on a small, stable, unique columns - like a numerical ID or something - **NOT** on such a huge, variable-length Unicode-string column. You should have a **good** clustered index on some appropriate column, and then add a **non-clustered** index on `RawData` and your query response time should be a fraction of what it is now....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. Your suggestion(and other posters) worked like a charm. I added a non-clustered (unique) index for the **RawData** column and my query took less than a second! (I also needed to remove the first wildcard as it was unnecessary as first item on row was domain name) Can you help me construct a query that uses the word table to check for domains that aren't English words?

Comment: That sounds like a whole, new question!

Comment: An RDBMS does not give you a lot of useful features for this kind of data to query, except if you have to attach other information to domain names. You may want to look at other kind of storage for data.

Comment: @marc_s Sorry I'm new to stack overflow. I assumed because it was related I could ask the question. Does etiquette require I post a different question on entirely new thread?

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to find a decent .com domain name so I downloaded complete list
>   of .com domains from Verisign with the aim of running some SQL queries
>   against it. One key goal is to run a query that checks dictionary
>   sized list of English words to see if any don't have a.com domain.

Forget about the idea. The pool of available domain names has been mined to death a long time ago. You are not the first to try the idea. The names that are still unregistered are obscure dictionary words that are not really usable and have no commercial use.

There are interesting things you can do, but finding good names 'overlooked' by others is not among them. But you will see for yourself.

Regarding the **parsing** of the **zone file**: here is what today's .com zone file looks like:

```
; The use of the Data contained in Verisign Inc.'s aggregated
; .com, and .net top-level domain zone files (including the checksum
; files) is subject to the restrictions described in the access Agreement
; with Verisign Inc.

$ORIGIN COM.
$TTL 900
@ IN    SOA     a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. (
                  1587225735 ;serial
                  1800 ;refresh every 30 min
                  900 ;retry every 15 min
                  604800 ;expire after a week
                  86400 ;minimum of a day
                  )
$TTL 172800
 NS A.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS G.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS H.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS C.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS I.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS B.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS D.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS L.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS F.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS J.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS K.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS E.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
 NS M.GTLD-SERVERS.NET.
COM. 86400 DNSKEY 257 3 8 AQPDzldNmMvZFX4NcNJ0uEnKDg7tmv/F3MyQR0lpBmVcNcsIszxNFxsBfKNW9JYCYqpik8366LE7VbIcNRzfp2h9OO8HRl+H+E08zauK8k7evWEmu/6od+2boggPoiEfGNyvNPaSI7FOIroDsnw/taggzHRX1Z7SOiOiPWPNIwSUyWOZ79VmcQ1GLkC6NlYvG3HwYmynQv6oFwGv/KELSw7ZSdrbTQ0HXvZbqMUI7BaMskmvgm1G7oKZ1YiF7O9ioVNc0+7ASbqmZN7Z98EGU/Qh2K/BgUe8Hs0XVcdPKrtyYnoQHd2ynKPcMMlTEih2/2HDHjRPJ2aywIpKNnv4oPo/
COM. 86400 DNSKEY 256 3 8 AwEAAbbFc1fjkBCSycht7ah9eeRaltnLDK2sVyoxkjC6zBzm/5SGgfDG/H6XEupT7ctgCvnqexainTIfa8nnBYCOtAec7Gd1vb6E/3SXkgiDaMUJXmdt8E7obtVZqjFlN2QNnTljfMiECn16rZXlvXIi255T1wFkWtp5+LUCiufsLTeKc9xbQw7y0ucsR+GKz4yEStbYi98fnB5nOzzWhRUclf0=
COM. 86400 DNSKEY 256 3 8 AwEAAcpiOic4s641IPlBcMlBWA0FFomUWuKDWN5CzId/la4aA69RFpakRxPSZM8fegOQ+nYDrUY6UZkQRsowPr18b+MqyvHBUaT6CJUBkdRwlVcD/ikpcjvfGEiH5ttpDdZdS/YKZLBedh/uMCDLNS0baJ+nfkmMZGkYGgnK9K8peU9unWbwAOrJlrK60flM84EUolIIYD6s9g/FfyVB0tE86fE=
COM. 86400 NSEC3PARAM 1 0 0 -
COM. 900 RRSIG SOA 8 1 900 20200425160215 20200418145215 39844 COM. ItE0mu9Hb2meliHlot2/6f0cMvCJThPps/BxbyRkDDYesfLBVXqtIRHiDN+wlf7HS+lxFtLHIUzT0GAPf2y5cA0s3pUdBxyRft0fC76GEJq7g0Tcpifdxft4T/6XTv77rP8pFE7aSp+SMDtUMRFIGnGTGBo7WRhjIx1G0peGXMr13xRg4Pa9kigGtjSRi3SWyNT9x1IjVVVJtsFzP9sELQ==
COM. RRSIG NS 8 1 172800 20200423045013 20200416034013 39844 COM. D9BeOQ8drx8LiXXBOk6KlxKacpno/tPujwOAPd482Kj+yAQkFxVVL1bqU03WA7c12W/mkLxk665OQDfOOoirqMePDuamvQCguaSFVKVm5no42JsxoitzwOo+g0kwm9u2F/xGO9ybPfcEQ/nrH9de/RluVSVc0MPsCMja2sCuohEMSYApMjFs4XcXsED0lFTzllIESW7JvK8xb8RFId0TOw==
COM. 86400 RRSIG NSEC3PARAM 8 1 86400 20200423045013 20200416034013 39844 COM. l37dFS1JFXDg9gr1oGACX2rI/iegsIX3RlAEpshuIsT4isZ0FAw0pkAVJQvyqd5a3IOO1TjczWN1U/eYB2ynvX1MKLg3NEp01zUo67eJgowjV+g3zF3XtifhoW///Tqqz0GuAk443jol/Ue00SX3k6XgzxbycX9GKR9FmsLaIIowvz991eJyL1mgOpzQvLnIL1/EAZi9felFilkrj5JaIA==
COM. 86400 RRSIG DNSKEY 8 1 86400 20200430182421 20200415181921 30909 COM. Zkw5YJzP75sdfLN8kN/y8/ywFX+DvotF6fVdxKQGdmgJyyUnDliP6q0VXqVpHHDwtW2WfOlwskiW6007+MIGqV5VtTL6tGeZLv4hJDYZkAwIrl/xBN+aQmIvan4UdBROkOAnfi5Atf1adX5iCqn1jfIGMXb8kKVMrDuDJc/V6XbXEL8NysnqRQtdC6bVuunDQOg/Edw1Uy+B9ly9njU/EmlISkNZo2jo+cXJBFS+Is/6Xcn04+jkHiSRuAFwaGPxKPLeG92v+5ea7pWXBpSIwiqD7Gp/yJCvCUrRZP8eJcoYGav0TT7Bsp2ml15dV20FmNnBPdTqKZHtT8HAIp60Qw==
KITCHENEROKTOBERFEST NS NS1.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITCHENEROKTOBERFEST NS NS2.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITCHENFLOORTILE NS NS1.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITCHENFLOORTILE NS NS2.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITCHENTABLESET NS NS1.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITCHENTABLESET NS NS2.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITEPICTURES NS NS1.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
KITEPICTURES NS NS2.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
BOYSBOXERS NS NS1.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
BOYSBOXERS NS NS2.UNIREGISTRYMARKET.LINK.
```

What you are interested in is the lines that contain `NS` in second position. In this example KITCHENEROKTOBERFEST.COM has two name servers declared. Since this is the .com zone file, .com has to be assumed when the name does not end with a dot. So you have to filter on those lines and remove duplicates. You should end up with about 140 million .com domain names. Definitely not 352 million - either you have duplicates or you have imported the wrong data.
That gives you an idea of how crowded the .com zone is. Don't be surprised that any name that remotely makes sense is already registered.

When you have loaded the data to a table, the remaining problem is **indexing** the data to achieve good performance while making queries. I understand this issue has now been addressed so I won't be making further suggestions on that.

One thing you can do to highlight pure dictionary domains is to do a JOIN of two tables: your domain table and the keyword table. This should need indexes on both sides to run optimally, and I don't have details about your table structure. Or try each keyword by one by one against the domain table in a loop (can use a cursor).

I too feel like this is a whole new question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I didn't know the numbers involved I assumed that the flat file import created some inaccurate records while trying to parse. Not sure whether cleaning up the data is worth it if I can work around it (will depend on performance on whether I try to clean it up).  I also assume many others have mined data in the manner I'm doing it anyways as a learning exercise. Could you help me write the query I need? There are two tables, Com and Words, One column in each.. Word (dictionary), RawData (domains) both now indexed.

Comment: For the record, I also want the dictionary search because ultimately I want to use it as a template to be able to also run against any table of words I create. (e.g. after this I'll create another table of words where I've branched out from official spelling by substituted or omitted letters)